# Error en sentencia SQL en access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Alguien podria decirme por favor cual es el error en esta sentencia o que es lo que falta?

```
select count(distinct BLART) from COV_SAP_AccP_LA where Country = "XXX"
```

Lo estoy haciendo en `access` y lo que quiero es que me cuente por separado los diferentes datos que hay en una columna.

El error que me aparece en pantalla es

> Syntax error(missing operator) in query expresion 'count(distinct BLART)'

Ya revisé varios ejemplos pero no se si `access` tiene una sintaxis diferente.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una sugerencia puede ser:

```
SELECT count(BLART) AS [Cantidad_datos], BLART
FROM COV_SAP_AccP_LA 
WHERE Country = "XXX"
GROUP BY BLART;
```

La anterior consulta genera como resultado la cantidad de datos *(en este caso, la cantidad de `BLART`)*.

Si *"por ejemplo"* existiese mas de un elemento en la columna `BLART`, solo mostrará el nombre una vez, pero en la columna `Cantidad_datos` se mostrará la cantidad de veces que existe.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu sugerencia Mauricio, me funciono perfectamente y es exactamente lo que necesitaba.

Comment: @Viatorii me alegro que este aporte le haya sido de utilidad. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomendaria agruparlos para que tengas una lista de los datos con sus concurrencias, esto lo haces de la siguiente manera.

```
select count(BLART) 
from ( select distinct BLART from COV_SAP_AccP_LA ) 
where Country = "XXX
```

Espero te ayude esto.

Saludos.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta,esa sentencia cuenta todos los datos  de la columna en general pero no cuenta por separado los tipos de datos que hay.

Comment: Con el GROUP By integrado tiene la misma funcion que un DISTINCT segun lo que entiendo es lo que quieres obtener.

Comment: Podria intentarlo entonces de la siguiente manera:

    select count(BLART) 
from
(
    select distinct BLART from COV_SAP_AccP_LA 
)
where Country = "XXX"